# How to Add an item to a specific index in a PagedCollectionView?

Tags: c#, silverlight

How to Add an item to a specific index in a PagedCollectionView?
We can add any item to a paged collection view but the problem is it adds it to the last..
I want to add it at any given index..!

Can any one pls help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not possible to add item at given position or index in PagedCollectionView**... To add item at given index you need to add item to underlying source. Check below example:

```
List<String> itemList = new List<String>();

// Generate some items to add to the list.
for (int i = 1; i <= 33; i++)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder("Item ");
    sb.Append(i.ToString());
    itemList.Add(sb.ToString());
}

// Add at given index
itemList.Insert(10, "Extra item");

// Wrap the itemList in a PagedCollectionView for paging functionality
var itemListView = new PagedCollectionView(itemList);
```

Comment: Please see this post. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467802/how-to-add-an-element-to-the-source-of-a-pagedcollectionview

Comment: We can easily add items to pagedcollectionview.

Comment: @ManishGupta - sorry you cannot add item in bettwen...i.e. at given loacation that add the item at the end....I think you question is about adding item at givein position not about that..

Comment: Hello Sir, I checked out your blogspot. It is really interesting. I also got many answers to my old Questions which were present in my mind.
Sir please can I add you on facebook so that I can be in touch??

Comment: @ManishGupta - my facebook page is is facebook.com/pranayamr there you can add me ..but i m not accesing frequently ..

Comment: Greetings sir,
Can you please see this Question:
Follow the link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528881/can-i-make-a-list-of-all-the-items-present-in-the-source-collection-of-a-paged-c